# loading tramp overrides tramp-remote-path customization back to default value

Tags: init-file, tramp, customize, autoload

I have customized `tramp-remote-path` in my .emacs.d/init.el with

```
(custom-set-variables  '(tramp-remote-path
    (quote
     (tramp-own-remote-path))))
```

but when tramp is loaded the value of tramp-remote-path is set to the default value. For example after I open a remote file the value of tramp-remote-path is `(tramp-default-remote-path   "/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" ...)`

I have verified this behaviour even when the above customization is the only code in init.el with both 24.5 and 25.0.

Why does this happen?

How can I prevent it and make my customization stick?

Since `tramp-remote-path` is defined using `defcustom`, it seems like it should be customizable with `custom-set-variables`

Comment: Try dropping the `(quote ...)` around the sexp `(tramp-own-remote-path)`.

Comment: @Drew That seems to make no difference

Comment: And try removing the parens around `tramp-own-remote-path`. Better yet, use `M-x customize-option` to customize the option, instead of trying to roll your own code to customize it.

Comment: @Drew The code in the question was saved from the customize interface.

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Maybe setq-default would work with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer: Don't edit custom-set-variables form by hand.

Tramp must be loaded for `custom-set-variables` to work. Either load tramp *before* `custom-set-variables`:

```
(require 'tramp)
(custom-set-variables  '(tramp-remote-path
    (quote
     (tramp-own-remote-path))))
```

Or see Michael's answer for a way to tell customize to load tramp first.  Note that using `M-x customize-variable RET tramp-remote-path RET` creates a correct custom-set-variables entry, of the form suggested by Michael.

---

#### Longer answer

The root of the problem seems to be in tramp's custom `###;;;tramp-autoload` annotation.  This tramp-specific mechanism more or less breaks basic `custom-set-variables` forms.

In normal operation, when you run `customize-set-variables`, Emacs does one of two things: if the variable already exists in context it sets it, and if it doesn't, it records the value (using `(set symbol value)`), relying on the customize machinery to use that saved value after the variable is declared (through a defcustom).

Then, when Emacs evaluates the corresponding defcustom (when loading the corresponding package, for example), the customize machinery checks whether the symbol being `defcustom`ed already has a value pending (using `(get symbol 'saved-value)`), and sets the symbol to that value if so. If there is no such pending value, it uses the value provided by the defcustom form (the default value).

As an exception, however, the `defcustom` implementation also checks that it isn't overriding an already set value. That is, if the variable has already been declared and given a value, then it's value is preserved. To check whether such a default value exists, `customize` calls `default-toplevel-value`. If there already is a default value set, it leaves the variable untouched.

The function that does this is `custom-initialize-reset`.

Well, in your case, the problem is precisely this exception. If you open `emacs/lisp/net/tramp-loaddefs.el`, you'll see the following:

```
(defvar tramp-remote-path '(tramp-default-remote-path "/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/local/bin" "/local/freeware/bin" "/local/gnu/bin" "/usr/freeware/bin" "/usr/pkg/bin" "/usr/contrib/bin" "/opt/bin" "/opt/sbin" "/opt/local/bin") "\
```

This is a way to forward declare `tramp-remote-path`, but as a side effect it declares and gives a default value to `tramp-remote-path`. That's fine as far as `custom-set-variables` is concerned, but not as far as `defcustom` is concerned. Thus, when the actual `defcustom` for `tramp-remote-path` is loaded, the aforementioned exception kicks in, and `customize` politely preserves the value set by the `defvar`, thereby ignoring your customization.

You can verify that this is the issue by adding

```
(defvar tramp-remote-path nil)
```

to your `.emacs`, before the actual call to `custom-set-variables`. That should fix it (because now `custom-set-variable` will think the variable exists), but I don't know enough about `customize` to recommend this solution.

Answer (score 3):

`tramp.el` must be loaded indeed when a Tramp user option shall be set. The proper way to do this is

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(tramp-remote-path (quote (tramp-own-remote-path)) nil (tramp)))
```

Maybe this shall be described in the Tramp manual.

Comment: Michael, I upvoted your answer to get it closer to the top, but isn't that arguably a bug?  Also, is there a way to get such a form from the customize interface (with the extra `nil (tramp)`? Normally custom-set-variables forms are not written by hand.

Comment: I suppose if you customize the variable in the customize interface, and if you save your settings then, you will get such a `custom-set-variables` call in your `.emacs`. I've described it this way, because many people hesitate to use the customize interface.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Thanks.  I'll update my own answer.

Comment: I think this is a bug. The `defcustom` declarations in tramp.el should have a `:require` clause so that `customize-variable` knows to add this.

Comment: Likely, it is a hen-and-egg problem. The additional `:require` argument in the `defcustom` declaration is active only, when tramp.el is already loaded.

Comment: I believe you can't use customize-variable on unloaded modules.

Comment: Sure. That's why I have proposed the respective call in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Fascinating. I can exactly reproduce what you're running in to if I try to use the `customization` interface. However! I can successfully change the value of `tramp-remote-path` by skipping the `customization` interface, either of two different ways.

First, tramp expects `tramp-remote-path` to be a list, so my inclination is to do this (in my `init.el`):

```
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/home/gastove/")
```

Or, setting to a single directory:

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-remote-path '("/home/gastove"))
```

Comment: This solves the main problem, but I would still like to understand why/how tramp resets customizations on load. Currently I am trying to keep configuration in customize when I can.